# PHP compare $_POST array members

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have a form where users have to enter timecodes or time values `00:00:00`,  which at the end must fulfill the condition that each timestamp must be larger than the previous.  I know it can be achieved by processing the $_POST['timecode'].  However can't make it work.  This is what I've been working around.  Sorry for my ignorance, but being sure this is the way and not getting the result drove me to ask here.

```
$q_tc=count($_POST['timecode']);
for ($w = 0; $w < $q_tc; $w++) {
    if ($_POST['id_ts'][$w] > $_POST['id_ts'][$w+1]) {
        echo "error: should be smaller than next timecode";
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What I get after running this code is that everytime an error message is deployed,  even without the condition being placed.

I'm running PHP 5.4 on a apache server.  This is what the  $_POST['timecode'] contains:

```
Array ( [0] => 00:00:30 [1] => 10:00:00 [2] => 12:00:00 )
```

And as it can be seen,  no error should be generated, but the code does not check accurately the requested condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You end up comparing the last one to a null value, because you look at 0 and 1, then 1 and 2, then 2 and 3, but key 3 doesn't exist.

Try this fix. Skip the first one, compare each to the previous.

```
$arr = array('00:00:30', '10:00:00', '12:00:00');
$q_tc=count($arr);
for ($w = 1; $w < $q_tc; $w++) {
    if ($arr[$w-1] > $arr[$w]) {
       echo "error: should be smaller than next timecode";
    }
}
```